# Laying out graphic heavy Android apps

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

What is the best way to lay out Android apps with lots of graphics. The entire screen is designed in photoshop, I then lay transparent buttons over the graphic in Eclipse. I've done this on iOS for a long time but on Android I can't find a layout which makes this possible. I basically want a relative layout without it snapping my buttons all over the place. I want to be able to size and layout buttons over the image with no interference. As it is so graphic heavy we have to redo the graphics and layouts for each device we support so the ways in which RelativeLayout are attempting to help are not needed.

Edit:

After more research it seems like I'm looking for AbsoluteLayout - but that's deprecated.

Comment: I think the best suggestion would be to develop a Custom Layout.

Comment: @silverback That's what I want to do, just drag/drop/size objects however I like on the screen without the OS layout system interfering. How can I create a custom layout?

Comment: "we have to redo the graphics and layouts for each device we support"... How many devices is that? It's possible to do what you want with a frame layout and excessive use of translation, but it's not very, umm... Android-y. There are literally thousands of different devices.

Comment: @Geobits I know. The graphics in these apps are quite unique and have become part of the app branding on iOS. It's becoming a nightmare on Android. I'm planning on designing screens for the top few Android devices just. Is there no easy way to tell Android - don't do anything with this layout, just let me place the items and leave them there (like layout out a UI on iOS).

Comment: *...but on Android I can't find a layout which makes this possible.* - because this is not how Android works. There are a lot of devices out there with different screen sizes and resolutions and the key to make your app work nicely on all of them is to make your layouts relative. So, you can't just use an image and place buttons at exact places and expect it to work on every device out there(if this is what you're asking).

Comment: @Luksprog That's what I'm asking. I know it won't work on all devices and I've explained this to my client. He wants to use the graphic heavy approach and only work on a couple of top used devices.

Comment: Hmm.. there are several ways, really. Like I said, a FrameLayout might work. Forgoing `View`s and using a `Canvas` is a possibility. You're really trying to work around the OS, though, so anything you do is apt to be error-prone and cumbersome. And yes, they deprecated `AbsoluteLayout` for this exact reason. They really don't *want* it to work this way.

Comment: Ok thanks for the responses. I might just ask my client to redesign the graphics. I suppose if we made the buttons the full width of the screen we could use a linear layout.

Comment: In the end you could make layouts specially designed for popular devices + use a generic layouts for the other phones(or using tricks like centering the entire layout, wrapping it in a `ScrollView` if the height is too small etc). But this is a horrific way of building an android app and the effort of building each of the screens might as well be used from the start to build the app like it should be built.

Comment: @Luksprog Definitely seems like I was going about this the wrong way. I'm going to get it redesigned so it'll fit nicely with a linear layout.

Comment: Also consider other ways of programming Android Apps such as HTML5 (Cordova/PhoneGap) or Monkey (http://www.monkeycoder.co.nz), there are others.